# How to connect Detox framework with XRay test management tool

Tags: detox

I have detox project and I would like to connect testing results from Detox to XRay test cases. In the past I was doing Cypress integration with TestRail and it was great where test results from Cypress were automatically imported to TestRail report. Can I achieve the same with Detox and XRay? I would appreciate if you can explain to me steps how to do that

I did not find a proper documentation how to connect Detox and Xray